# Scala convert ArrayList in Map[String, Any] to Seq

Tags: java, scala, arraylist, yaml

I'm trying to read in a `.yaml` file into my Scala code. Assume I have the following `yaml` file:

```yaml
animals: ["dog", "cat"]
```

I am trying to read it using the following code:

```scala
val e = yaml.load(os.read("config.yaml")).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]]
val arr = e.getOrDefault("animals", new Java.util.ArrayList[String]()) // arr is Option[Any], but I know it contains java.util.ArrayList<String>
arr.asInstanceOf[Buffer[String]] // ArrayList cannot be cast to Buffer
```

The ArrayList is type Any, so how do I cast to a Scala Collection e.g. Buffer? (Or Seq, List...)

Comment: Donald, your question has enough answers. Will you please comments/accept/else on those? Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

SnakeYaml (assuming what you're using) can't give you a scala collection like Buffer directly.

But you can ask it for ArrayList of string and then convert it to whatever you need.

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
val list = arr.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[String]].asScala
```

results in:

```
list: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = Buffer(dog, cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is to define the model of you configuration, for example:

```
class Sample {
  @BeanProperty var animals = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
}
```

The following will create an instance of `Sample`:

```
val input = new StringReader("animals: [\"dog\", \"cat\"]")
val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[Sample]))
val sample = yaml.load(input).asInstanceOf[Sample]
```

Then, using [`CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) in Scala 2.13, or [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) in Scala 2.12 or prior, convert `animals` into a Scala structure:

```
val buffer = sample.getAnimals.asScala
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/pWRJIgPdQTWtl2Md23bIWw/5).